# Modifying a variable in enclosing scope

Tags: scope, opa

There is a common problem in languages that assume variable declarations are local. How do you get at variables in enclosing scopes.

Is there a way in Opa?

For example:

```
start() = 
    name = Random.string(5)

    set_name(new_name) = 
        old_name = name
        name = new_name
        log("User {old_name} changed name to {new_name}")
```

This doesn't work. We get a warning that `name` is unused in `set_name`, and the value of `name` in `start` is never changed.

In a language like Lua, Javascript or Scheme, there is explicit marking of locals, so variables not marked in that way can be found in the scope stack. In Python there is no such marking, and so this would be impossible. In Python you can get at global (toplevel) variables, and I've found the `@toplevel` directive in Opa too. But I'm interested in intermediate points in the scope chain.

There are workarounds, of course, by using records, but is there a direct route?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution is to use Reference module :

Reference.create, Reference.get, Reference.set

http://opalang.org/resources/doc/index.html#stdlib.core.reference.opa.html/!/value_stdlib.core.Reference

Comment: Incidentally the links may have changed. This worked for me: http://opalang.org/resources/doc/index.html#reference.opa.html/!/value_stdlib.core.Reference

Answer (score 1):

Reference module mentioned in Fred's answer is indeed one solution to this and it's closest to what you are asking for.

But it's also good to know that when programming the "right way" most of the state in your Opa program will be captured in [Sessions](http://opalang.org/resources/doc/index.html#stdlib.core.rpc.core.session.opa.html/!/value_stdlib.core.rpc.core.Session), with a change to the session's state triggered by a message send to it.

Comment: Thanks. Part of the trick of learning a new language is learning the idioms and the culture. I'm a day into Opa now, and while it is very intuitive, I'm sure I'm missing the one-true-way kind of solutions. I've accepted Fred's answer, but I'll definitely read up on Sessions.

Comment: Incidentally your link didn't work for me, but this one did: http://opalang.org/resources/doc/index.html#session.opa.html/!/value_stdlib.core.rpc.core.Session

Comment: Btw. you can read more about sessions in my recent blog post: http://blog.opalang.org/2011/09/sessions-handling-state-communication.html